# Creating a unique object on years and months based on array of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a unique object of years and months based on an array of dates, see what I mean below:

```
const availableDates = ["26-01-2022", "30-01-2022", "02-03-2022", "16-04-2022", "01-01-2023"]; // This list will be really long, just an example
```

I want to create a unique object like below using availableDates but having issues trying to figure it out:

```
const uniqueDates = {
  "2022": ["Jan", "Mar", "Apr"],
  "2023": ["Jan"]
};
```

If you have a better way that I achieve this, please let me know!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use Array.reduce to create the desired map, and using a Set to ensure we only keep a unique set of months for each year.

```js
const availableDates = ["26-01-2022", "30-01-2022", "02-03-2022", "16-04-2022", "01-01-2023", "01-01-2023"];

const months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
const uniqueDates = availableDates.reduce((acc, dt) => { 
    let [day, month, year] = dt.split("-");
    acc[year] = [...new Set(acc[year] || []).add(months[month - 1])];
    return acc;
}, {})


console.log("Unique object:", uniqueDates)
```

Comment: Reduce is very handy indeed! Good luck with the project!!

Comment: I'm weirdly getting duplicate months in a year but only one duplicate, just trying to debug it

Comment: I'll try to reproduce that issue, I think it may be a case of moving a bracket!

Comment: I think I've fixed it, the issue occurred for me if the last two dates were in the same month and year.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I did use an .includes to see if it existed but your approach is cleaner and keeping to the Set features, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```js
let month = {
  "01" : "Jan",
  "02" : "Feb",
  "03" : "Mar",
  "04" : "Apr",
  // ...
};
let res = ["26-01-2022", "30-01-2022", "02-03-2022", "16-04-2022", "01-01-2023"].reduce((acc, el) => {
   let arr = el.split("-");
   if( acc[arr[2]] && !acc[arr[2]].includes(month[arr[1]])){
      acc[arr[2]].push(month[arr[1]])
   } else if(!acc[el[2]]){
      acc[arr[2]] = [month[arr[1]]]
   }
   return acc;
}, {})
console.log(res)
```